# How to format the output in a for loop

Tags: c++, output, output-formatting, outputformat

Hello I have this output as below:

```
NixonOp      11.99      Operations
Cable Management      29.59      IT Department
Server Maintenance      30.5915      IT Department
Management Lessons      89.541      Management
O-Class      155.514      IT Department
MngAPP      174.99      IT Department
```

I would like to be this way:

```
NixonOp              11.99      Operations
Cable Management     29.59      IT Department
Server Maintenance   30.5915    IT Department
Management Lessons   89.541     Management
O-Class              155.514    IT Department
MngAPP               174.99     IT Department
```

The problem is that all the values that are shown here are part of 3 vectors, one for the name, one for the price and one for the department (last column) and are outputted by using a for loop. Is there any way to make it look like this?

Comment: You can use `std::setw` for the numbers to set the output width.

Comment: @WernerHenze I tried with setw() function but it just shows a total chaos as some of are longer and some are shorter

Comment: `setw` will work for the numbers. For the strings you can check the string length and then output enough spaces to fill up for a given column width.

Comment: @HermesÇati you have to actually find out which the largest elements size in each column and then set for that column. and then you have to change that every time you print a new column

Comment: See the example on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width)